# jQuery - What does this syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking at jquery.ui-1.8.11.js:

```
$.extend(Datepicker.prototype, {
    /* Class name added to elements to indicate already configured with a date picker. */
    markerClassName: 'hasDatepicker',

    /* Debug logging (if enabled). */
    log: function () {
        if (this.debug)
            console.log.apply('', arguments);
    },
```

What is that `log: function()` syntax?  What's it called?  How can it be used?

Comment: It's just an option provided to the new prototype being specified. Most likely used to handle logging events on the new object. "If something needs to be logged, call this function if debugging is enabled"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to an `$.extend` call is an Object.  They're defined using curly braces `{}` and take `key: value` pairs.  The value can be a function, which is what is happening for the `log`.

This is analogous to the following:

```
var myObject = {
  prop1: 'some value',
  prop2: 'some other value',
  method1: function () {
    // some code here.
  }
}
```

You can later call `myObject.method1()` to perform whatever the code inside the function is.

Answer (score 2):

It is extending the object properties on the `Datepicker.prototype` object.

For example, after that statement is run, you could do:

```
 alert(new Datepicker().markerClassName); // alert('hasDatepicker');

 // OR

 new Datepicker().log(); // calls the function
```

Basically, `$.extend()` allows you to modify an object with additional properties (or overwrite them). Consider the following object:

```
 var obj = { Text: 'Hello World' };

 alert(obj.Text); // Hello World

 $.extend(obj, {
     Text: 'Something Else',
     func: function() { alert('Stuff'); }
 });

 alert(obj.Text); // Something Else
 obj.func();
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax uses JavaScript prototyping to extend a Datepicker object and add additional attributes and functions. This adds Datepicker.log as a function and Datepicker.markerClassName.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument (begun with an opening curly brace `{` and ended with a closing curly brace `}`) to the `$.extend()` call is an **Object literal**. Generally speaking, it's shorthand for explicitly creating an object with `new Object`. These are roughly equivalent:

```
var foo = new Object;
foo.bar = 'bar';
```

and

```
var foo = {
    bar: 'bar'
};
```

It's also worth noting that the way functions are assigned, they are anonymous functions being assigned as values to properties of the object. As in:

```
var foo = new Object;
foo.method1 = function() { ... };
```

It is also possible to use named functions:

```
function fn1() { ...}
foo.method2 = fn1;
```

Or:

```
foo.method3 = function fn2() { ... };
```

Or:

```
var foo = {
    method4: function fn3() { ... }
};
```

There are other literals useful for shorthand in JavaScript, such as the Array literal:

```
var arr = ['members', 'are', 'separated', 'by', 'commas'];
```

And the RegExp literal (note that parsing a RegExp literal does not have the same escaping rules as passing a string to `new RegExp()`):

```
var exp = /some pattern/g; // Modifiers are after the closing slash
```